# I've problem on Bearing of a ligature with next letter typed after it in Unicode font

Tags: web-fonts, font-design, font-forge, ligatures, spacing

I'm new to font developing with FontForge; I'm sorry if I use any technical words incorrectly.

I've created a ligature with two glyphs. When the glyphs are typed separately they maintain the spacing between letters. But the issue occurs where the ligature should be intersecting with next letter: there is no kerning applied in anywhere in the project.

Can anybody explain why is it happening and how can I prevent it??

[image: Picture Shows the lines of glyph.]

In the above image you can clearly see if I type "Tk" or "kT" it looks good - the ligatures occur as expected. But when I type "Tik" the Ti allows 'k' to intersect but none of the glyph beyond there, left or right boundary box/Bearing and I did not apply any kerning between them.

I don't want this to happen.

Does anyone here know how to prevent this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi I edited your query for clarity, spelling and grammar - please look over and make sure I didn't butcher your meaning when I did so - if I did you can revert it easily. Hope this helps you get some responses.

Comment: Also -  Welcome to **GD.SE** - Please look through [tour] to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. Then look over [ask] and [answer] a question to see what makes a good query here, and how best to frame it. I'm unsure how many folks here are good Fontforge power users, but I suspect we've a few folks who may be able to help!

Comment: It looks like when you use the "Ti" ligature it still has the width of the original "T", so the next letter gets offset. Have you checked the width of the ligature in every possible way? (I'm no expert in FontForge. Never made ligatures.)

Comment: Can you open a metric window (Ctrl + K), activate *View → Show Grid → Show,* type the letter combo in question and show the result? Also: The ligature does not look identical in your pictures. Once the bar is crossing the *C*-like structure; once it isn’t.